# I need help fixing this list's indices error, please

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to reorder a list so that instead of looking like this:

```
Boris, 1, Johnson
Noah, 2, Miller
Liam, 3, Johnson
```

It looks like this

```
Boris Johnson, 1
Noah Miller, 2
Liam Johnson, 3
```

my code looks like this:

```
firstNames = []
numbers = []
lastNames = []

with open("lab9data.txt") as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
    for i in contents:
        x, y, z = i.split(',')
        firstNames.append(x)
        numbers.append(int(y))
        lastNames.append(z)
        f.write(firstNames[i]+lastNames[i]+', '+(str(numbers[i]))+'\n')
print(firstNames[0])  #test
print(numbers[0])   #test
print(lastNames[0])    #test
```

When I try to run this code it gets an error that says this:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can someone please help me fix this error?

Comment: Where did this error occur? Please provide the full traceback

Comment: This error occured at line f.write(firstNames[i]+lastNames[i]+', '+(str(numbers[i]))+'\n')

Comment: That means `i` is a `string object` and not an `integer`. Change `for i,content in enumerate(contents)` that will make i an integer

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain it just a bit more? Im not for sure what you are asking, please rephrase it

Comment: write `print(type(i))` and `print(i)`after `for i in contents:` line... you will see that `i` is an alphabet and not a number.. you can't do `firstNames['B']`... lists don't accept strings (as the error is saying) instead you should be doing `firstNames[0]`

Comment: Hw would I be able to just switch from firstNames[i] to firstNames[0]? Wouldn't it just print out the first value in the list, and not cycle through the list like it would do for i?

Comment: Change your `for i in contents:` line to `for i,content in enumerate(contents)`. Also take a look into [`enumerate`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/)

Comment: Ok i switched my line from for i in contents to for i, content in enumerate(contents).......but now I have a new error message     AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'.....this is from the line where i split the file into three lists

Comment: `x, y, z = i.split(',')` -> `x, y, z = content.split(',')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223498/discussion-between-dylanwinter-and-yatin).

Comment: @Yatin contents is a list not a string

Answer (score 1):

The error is most likely due to the fact the you are passing 'i' which is a string as an index value for accessing the items of the list.

```
print(i)
>>> 'Boris, 1, Johnson'
```

Try something like

```
For index, i in enumerate(contents):
   ...
   ...
   ... firstNames[index] + lastNames[index] ...
```

You will also get error at f.write() because you have opened the file as read only.

Here is the complete answer.

```
with open('lab9data.txt') as f1, \
     open('lab9data_2.txt', 'w') as f2:
    contents = f1.readlines()
    for i in contents:
        # The strip function removes whitespace and newlines.
        first_name, number, last_name = [
            string.strip(' ').strip('\n') for string in i.split(',')
        ]
        f2.write(first_name
                 + ' '
                 + last_name
                 + ', '
                 + number
                 + '\n'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("lab9data.txt") as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
    for i in contents:
        x, y, z = i.strip('\n').split(',')
        print(x + z + ', ' + (str(y))+'\n')
```

If this works then convert the last print to write to file statement.